# Domain names for production / development server best practice

Tags: development-environment, production-environment

Ok so I have a number of CMSs and eCommerce applications, that require the correct URL (otherwise the links will not work). Of course in my development server, the domain name cannot be the same as the production server... do you guys just do an edit/replace on all files and edit the mysql entries before pushing the development to production server environment? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score -2):

You could just place everything in a directory with a random hex or other valid characters as the name like:

**yourdomain.com/XHTEDD12222-112KJK**

You might also want to include an entry in your robots.txt file to exclude this directory. This isn't 100% safe, and it is best to use a local server or access the site via IPv6. IPv6 is suggested over IPv4 for security with crawlers. Anything you put up publicly isn't exactly safe.

Once you change the name with one of the above options, you could just refactor your project with the name change. If you go with IP and or local server, you can refactor to that number and it should still work.

You may also look into editing host files to achieve a similar workaround without redirecting DNS servers to point at your development server, but this is OS dependent. Comment your OS and I might be able to help with that.

Lastly, for security, you could include a PHP wrapper for all of your pages that look for a specific IP address in `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` global variable, but this could get really complicated to implement and I'm unaware of any currently available components that do this.